# Cant use Flutter Facaebook Login on all devices

Tags: facebook, flutter, dart

i'm using `flutter_facebook_login 3.0.0` to make user login into app using their facebook account and everything going well, but when i just published the app on stores (google play) the facebook login doesn’t work on every android devices when download the app throw the google play store.

the plugin work 100% on all devices in debug mode, but in release and from store doesn’t work on all android devices  it's just stop on continue as .... and nothing happens!

can any body use it before help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

did you add the SHA-1 fingerprint of the release-apk to firebase and facebook?

If you are using [Google Play App Signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) you need to use the SHA1 from google play since Google will replace your release signing key with the one on googles server

[image]

alo make sure you added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to your manifest file

Comment: no i just add the key into facebook app and yeah i added every thing to the app configuration ? is this key the same in facebook app ?

Comment: Check your app store adminboard and extract the sha-fingerprint and add it to your facebook and google auth admin pages